# How to get a record that isn't connected to other records

Tags: sql, relationship

I have 1 person (entity) that has a relationship to many classes (1:N) , I need to get all the people that has no class connected to, using Sql query, how do I do that?

Comment: Can you describe persons and classes tables?

Comment: person has personId and and class has classId and personId

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result, as formatted text (not images.) Make it easy to assist you - [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return all the personId that exist in persons but have not record in classes:

```
select p.PersonId from Persons p where p.PersonId NOT IN (Select distinct c.PersonId from Classes c)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select p.* from Persons left outer join Classes C on p.personId = c.personId where c.classId Is Null
```

use this query to get the list of people that has no class connected to.

Comment: Hi @Dinesh, I see you're a new user. StackOverflow requests that answers have some text to explain something about the problem they solve (for example, if I don't have the question in front of me, do I know what problem your answer solves? Probably not). Please edit your answer and add a brief explanation.